# Responsive diamond shape with center aligned content using transform rotate

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform, centering

I am having great difficulties trying to create a centered, responsive diamond shape in the center of a 100% x 100% container, with the diamond containing a center aligned logo. Sound confusing? Well, this is what I mean:

(images are self-drawn graphics)

[image]

I have managed to get the responsive diamond shape working fine and is centered in the window using this:

```
.cover-diamond {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 25%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    border: solid 1px #EBC65A;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

But feeling rather suicidal after attempting to center the `<img>` logo in the middle, as this is the result:

[image]

I have tried many variations and have totally lost track of what I have tried. I tried `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` What is the correct way to do this?

**EDIT:**

A couple of concerns is that fact I am using an 80% wide image with an unknown height and the fact the sqaure (diamond now) has an unknown height too, because of the 25% bottom padding.

Please [take a look at my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ldqyjut/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can have top *and* bottom padding on `cover-diamond`:

```
padding: 12.5% 0;
```

… you can simply prepend `translateY(-50%)` to your transform:

```
transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
```

You can also remove these styles:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8704efrh/)